# Session Property not saving in session store when retrieving from socket.io

Tags: express, socket.io, passport.js

What I am trying to accomplish is to store the username of the current user in the session, such that it can be retrieved by socket.io.

Currently, I have the client sent its sessionId to the socket.io endpoint (via io.connect):

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost?sessionId=' + sessionid);
```

and then on the server side, I have:

```
io.use(function(socket, callback) {

    if (socket && socket.handshake && socket.handshake.query && socket.handshake.query.sessionId) {
        var sessionId = socket.handshake.query.sessionId;
        sessionStore.get(sessionId, function(error, session) {
            socket.handshake.sessionId = sessionId;

            if (error) {
                callback('Could not set session id with socket io authorization handshake!', false);
            } else if (!session) {
                callback('There was no session found during socket io authorization handshake!', false);
            } 

            console.log(session);

            socket.session = session;
            callback(null, true);
        });
    } else {
        callback('No sessionId value was provided in query string to socket io connect from client', false);
    }
});
```

This correctly retrieves the session from the client-provided sessionid (assuming the id exists, of course).

Now, what I want to do is be able to is get the passportjs-managed username accessible from within the socketio handlers, via the session.

So, to start with, I have this code in the router controller for this endpoint:

```
router.get('/',  Authentication.redirectIfNotAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    req.session.user = req.user;
    console.log(req.session);

    res.locals.sessionId = req.session.id;
    res.render('mypage', { title: 'This is my page', user: req.user });
});
```

That `console.log(req.session)` does show me that the req.user has been correctly inserted into the session object and is visible. Authentication.redirectIfNotAuthenticated is using passportjs and is really simple (code included incase it is the issue):

```
redirectIfNotAuthenticated : function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }

    res.redirect('/');
}
```

So...we know that the user is being inserted as a property into the session object...but when I hit one of my socketio methods:

```
socket.on('init', function(info) {
    console.log(socket.session);
    ...
});
```

*That* `console.log(socket.session)` does not show the session that I modified in the route, but shows the "original" session object - as though I never added anything to it at all! I do know that `socket.on('init'...` is being called after my `io.use(function....` code as detailed above (where the session is pulled from the sessionStore and saved in the socket object).

I just haven't been able to track down why the session, as stored in socket.session (as retrieved from the session store), isn't mirroring the latest changes made to the session in the router.

If anyone has any suggestions, or reasons why what I expect to see is incorrect, I would be happy to hear them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A session scopes a connection between a dedicated client browser tab and a server.

As you did not explain why you want to store the username in the session I can base my answer only on guesses:

1. If you want to remember the username for later use in the session store it on the client side.
2. If you want to declare the user name (and other variables) to other users in the communication space the easiest way to do that is to store the data in a database (mind that databases can be in-memory, which works out to be quick). You could also fittle with files - but if you run mutliple users you will have to switch to a database anyway...

In any way there is no need to extend the scope of a session over multiple clients.

Comment: I believe you nailed my use-case with 2. I do wish to declare the username to other users, but I guess that should be done via some other information rather than the session (via session ID), correct? As you said, a session scopes a connection between an instance of a client and the server (whereas I was treating it as the identifier of a user...which isn't incorrect, per se, but probably not the ideal method).

Comment: Correct. If the truth of the user is critical you need to cover this via authentication - passwords and usernames are for the database. The information, if a user is authenticated can be stored in the session on server. However such authentication status is something you would not communicate accross session border lines in the first place. For information purposes you could additionally store it in the database to let other people know.